# unable to give storyboard constraints correctly Xcode 6.4

Tags: layout, uiimage, xcode6, storyboard, constraints

My storyboard has many `labels` and `UIImages` .
I'm able to setup `constraints` for `iPhone 4.0 inches` but layout is not correct for `iPhone 6 , iPhone 6+ , iPhone 4s` 
for example on small screen `iPhone 4s` , some of my `labels` are absent and on iPhone 6 and 6+ , there is a huge distance between each `label` and `UIImage` .
I used pin for `width` and `height` and added all the missing constraints .
then used `leading space` , `trailing` , `bottom` ,`top` etc.
I have applied all types of permutations and combination of all these things.
Any suggestions for the layout as i have tried all the methods .